# The style file: siam.bst Database file #1: /Users/itz/Desktop/Salemoche/ZHdK/BA/Thesis/References/ba.bib Warning--empty journal in ref:swan

Tags: bibliographies

I'm trying to get my head around latex for my bachelor thesis and have had to deal with this bibliography subject for about 3 hours now without any progress so please, can someone help me? I've tried numerous things and get all kind of errors, but all of which come from the bibtex compiler.

This is my .tex document which i basically copied from tutorials, i don't suppose that i made a mistake since it didn't work with the bare minimum either, but you never know

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % clickable references
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % order reference numbers

\usepackage{graphicx} % import images
\usepackage{float} % control float positions
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Gabriel Bach}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \line(1,0){200}\\
        [1cm]
        Hello, World! \\
        \line(1,0){200}\\
        \begin{flushright}
        \textsc{
        Gabriel
        Bach\\
        ZHdK
        }
        \end{flushright}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

% Front Matter  _________________________________

\section*{Summary} % *removes numbering in title
    blabliblu   

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Summary}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\cleardoublepage % moves everything after to a new page

% List of Figures  _________________________________

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}List of Figures}

% Table of Contents  _________________________________

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty} % remove page number
\cleardoublepage 
\setcounter{page}{1}




% Body  _________________________________

\section{Introduction}\label{intro}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
    Hello, World!
    Blablablabla aösdjfaösdifj aösdifjasöodifjaw efoöaiejwöfoa weöfoijaoösdfijeaöwofi aöoeifj ölaksdjf aöosi dfaölsdfj öo \cite{ref:swan}

\newpage

\section{Bla bli blu}\label{scnd__paragraph}
    ölkasjdfölaisjdf öaoisjdflö aösdijf asödifj fsdlf 
\subsection{subsection}
    \begin{figure}[h] % h for here
        \centering
        \caption[This is my optional Caption]{this is my real caption}

    \end{figure}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
    you can find this on page \pageref{intro}
    This is the reference \cite{ref:swan} % cite key from bibdesk

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hey
        \item 'sup
        \begin{itemize}
            \item asdöf
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

    \cleardoublepage

% Bibliography _________________________________


    \bibliographystyle{siam}
    \bibliography{/Users/itz/Desktop/Salemoche/ZHdK/BA/Thesis/References/ba}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}References}
    \cleardoublepage

% Appendix  _________________________________

    \appendix
    \section{Appendix}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Apendix}


\end{document}
```

I compiled my file with bibdesk first, then tried to write my own file and eventually used mendeley, all of which failed

```
    %% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
    %% http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/

    %% Created for user at 2017-12-03 15:43:59 +0100 


    %% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 



    @article{ref:swan,
Author = {Nassim Nicholas Taleb},
Date-Added = {2017-12-02 16:40:54 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2017-12-02 16:41:25 +0000},
Title = {The Black Swan: The Impact of the Highly Improbable},
Year = {2007},
Bdsk-File-1 = {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}}
```

Can someone tell me, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Every `article` needs to have a journal field with the name of the journal.

Comment: Doing a quick google search reveals: You should use the `book` entry type.

Comment: thank you
i knew it might have been something with the .bib file, but i always assumed it should have given me an error while compiling and/or tell me that the references are not correct

Comment: But it does tell you that. Warning: Empty journal for ref:swan

Comment: Off-topic: You should load the `hyperref` package last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bibliography style that's in use specifies, for each BibTeX entry type, which fields are (a) required, (b) optional, or (c) ignored (i.e., all fields which are neither required nor optional).

The only entry type that has *no required fields*, and thus only optional and ignored fields, is `@misc`, the "catch-all" entry type.

The `siam` bib style, which has been around nearly unchanged since 1987, has the following formal specifications for the entry type `@article`:

- required fields: `author`, `title`, `journal`, and `year`;
- optional fields: `volume`, `number`, `pages`, and `note`;
- ignored fields: all others

The entry type `@article` should be used only for pieces published in journals. In the case you present -- a book -- it is simply not correct to employ the `@article` entry type. Since the entry (unsurprisingly) lacks a `journal` field, BibTeX issues a warning to this effect.

For sure, a more appropriate entry would be:

```
@book{ref:swan,
  author    = "Nassim Nicholas Taleb",
  title     = "The Black Swan: The Impact of the Highly Improbable",
  year      = 2007,
  publisher = "Random House",
  address   = "New York",
}
```

When working with the `siam` bibliography style and entries of type `@book`, the fields `author` or `editor`, `title`, `year` and `publisher` are required; the fields `volume`, `number`, `series`, `edition`, and `note` are optional; and all other fields are ignored. E.g., even if you provided an `isbn` field, it would be ignored by the `siam` bibliography style. (Other, more recent, bibliography styles do not ignore the `isbn` field.)